# creating sprite animation from sprite sheet cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to create an animated sprite from a sprite sheet, to do this I'm running the following:

```
NSMutableArray *bunsenAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 74; ++i) {
        [bunsenAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"15_%i.png", i]]];
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 74; ++j) {
        [bunsenAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"15_1.png"]]];
    }

    for (int k = 75; k <= 148; ++k) {
        [bunsenAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"15_%i.png",k]]];
    }

    for (int l = 1; l <= 74; ++l) {
        [bunsenAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"15_1.png"]]];
    }

    NSLog(@"bunsenAnimFrames is %@", bunsenAnimFrames );

    CCAnimation *bunsenAnimationAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:bunsenAnimFrames delay:1/25];

    bunsens = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:bunsenAnimationAnimation]];
```

Then later during populating a stage with a set of tiled sprites I run:

```
else if (blockValue == 2 || blockValue == 3 || blockValue == 4 || blockValue == 5) {
                bunsen = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"15_1.png"];

                if (blockValue == 2) {
                    bunsen.rotation = 90;
                }
                else if (blockValue == 3) {
                    bunsen.rotation = 180;
                }
                else if (blockValue == 4) {
                    bunsen.rotation = 270;
                }
                float tileY = screenSize.height-((countery*startData4)+startData4/2+77.5)/2;
                float tileX = ((counterx*startData4)+startData4/2+5)/2;

                bunsen.position = ccp(tileX,tileY);

                [bunsenAnimation addChild:bunsen];
                [bunsen runAction:bunsens];


            }
```

This works perfectly well in adding the bunsen sprite (declared as a sprite in header file) however on calling `[bunsen runAction:bunsens];` nothing happens to the sprite, any reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions I found for this was not using a fraction in the delay for CCAnimation... strange! as I thought the delay value could be any float!